# Why are Windows Terminal and PowerShell so very inefficient compared to cmd.exe, and how to make them fast?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-terminal

I run PHP CLI on Windows 10. I have installed Windows Terminal via winget. For several reasons, I have **long** tried to switch from using cmd.exe to using either PowerShell or Windows Terminal for my PHP CLI scripts.

But, after spending a full day on experimenting with this, I have determined the following:

1. Launching 100 PHP CLI scripts with cmd.exe barely is noticeable in CPU and RAM usage. I do this all the time. (Automatically, in the background, all launching minimized and grouping to the same Taskbar icon, performing all kinds of tasks concurrently.)
2. Launching 100 PHP CLI scripts with PowerShell or Windows Terminal (**yes, even with new tabs instead of new separate instances!**) causes my powerful computer to become unusable. All CPU and tons of RAM is used, and all kinds of error messages start popping up and the Taskbar icon becomes impossible to click to show the windows; everything "glitches out".
3. If I execute a command such as "php test.php" directly, without any terminal attached, it opens a PHP-branded window of some sort, but appears to use a cmd.exe "behind the scenes", so this is just the same as explicitly using cmd.exe.

My conclusion is that it's practically impossible to use anything other than cmd.exe for PHP CLI. I have searched, asked and experimented a lot related to this.

The main reason I needed to switch from cmd.exe in the first place is that the [window changes styles whenever a PowerShell command is called](https://superuser.com/questions/1777585/how-to-prevent-the-calling-of-powershell-in-php-cli-from-messing-up-the-cmd-exe?noredirect=1#comment2773799_1777585) from a PHP CLI script which was launched as/with cmd.exe, which does not happen if I use PowerShell or Windows Terminal.

But since both PowerShell and Windows Terminal are so extremely resource-hungry, I just cannot use them.

Is there some secret way to launch "minimal" versions of them or something? It doesn't seem like I could even buy a machine powerful enough to power my (relatively) few CLI instances.

I did not expect this to be an issue, and I don't understand how it can be the case no matter how "advanced" these terminals may be.

Comment: Please add some screenshots of the error messages popups that you get.

Comment: Look at `Powershell /?` options from command line. There are switches to pass to powershell.exe such as `-NoProfile` or `-NonInteractive` that may help make the powershell.exe footprint smaller. I would never process 100 processes at the same time concurrently and ensure whatever scripted processes I am launching is optimized for the system which is it running, throttle or queue the processes for x thread, etc. I don't see why you need 100 terminal sessions active anyway and you should log your processes and look at the logs for whatever you need the terminal open for output wise, etc.

Comment: So change your 'terminal sessions open per PHP CLI execution' and figure out whatever ultimate goal you have (reason you need 100 instances opened and minimized, tabs, etc.) and figure out a more optimized way to handle the task per whatever "requirement" constraints you have. PowerShell is not cmd so if you must use PowerShell, this is a downside, time to change strategy. Take that back to the powers that tell you any new requirements and let them know this is a downside to the technology and then brainstorm and test to optimize your processes on the system you run them with the tool you use.

Comment: We cannot tell you why different programs behave differently, we aren't the devs. I recommend you edit your question including the title, to remove this unanswerable part and focus on an specific question we CAN answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If I execute a command such as "php test.php" directly, without any terminal attached, it opens a PHP-branded window of some sort, but appears to use a cmd.exe "behind the scenes", so this is just the same as explicitly using cmd.exe.

It does not. Rather, *both* php.exe and cmd.exe (and PowerShell.exe, for that matter) use the same kind of automatic console window that is nowadays known as "Conhost" as of Vista, previously part of CSRSS in XP.

Conhost is the built-in terminal/console that is automatically opened for all such apps that have the 'console' flag set in their .exe files (though until Windows 8.1 it did not have any of the Unix-style terminal control capabilities, hence the term "console" rather than "terminal").

(It's actually Conhost that also "remembers" the console window appearances per-executable and/or per-shortcut, causing e.g. the PowerShell.exe console to have a blue background by default – though I suspect PowerShell may also deliberately tweak its console *font* on startup as well.)

Cmd.exe and PowerShell on their own have no visual appearance (not counting the old PowerShell ISE, that is) – they both always run either in Conhost or in Windows Terminal, with the OS automatically opening Conhost if needed. (As of Windows 11, the OS can automatically open Windows Terminal instead.)

> Launching 100 PHP CLI scripts with PowerShell or Windows Terminal (yes, even with new tabs instead of new separate instances!) causes my powerful computer to become unusable. All CPU and tons of RAM is used, and all kinds of error messages start popping up and the Taskbar icon becomes impossible to click to show the windows; everything "glitches out".

Windows Terminal uses GPU rendering (as does the Windows 10 Start Menu UI), so I'm guessing this probably indicates inefficiencies in its architecture, causing them to compete for resources. Try to enable the alternative "Atlas" rendering engine through its profile settings.

> Is there some secret way to launch "minimal" versions of them or something? It doesn't seem like I could even buy a machine powerful enough to power my (relatively) few CLI instances.

You're already doing that. The Conhost console window you get when running either php.exe or cmd.exe is as minimal as it gets.

Comment: If they all use the same console window, why is powershell so much slower? Why does the OP experience different results? I can attest to cmd.exe being faster than powershell.exe for running multiple instances of another program.

Comment: Depends on which part of it is actually slower? PowerShell _itself_ is slow to start up, but I'm not sure when the "other program" comes in, in your case.

Comment: "the other program" as you put it is just a binary that does something. The whole problem is that calling that binary through windows terminal or powershell is slower and hogs more resources than cmd. Hence the question how to make that faster.

Comment: Again, _which part_ of it? Does the binary itself occupy more memory or take more CPU to perform the same task when it's run from within PowerShell, or does PowerShell just take longer to spawn the binary initially? Is it the binary, or the PowerShell process, or the Conhost/WindowsTerminal process that's using those resources?

Comment: I understand your question now. In my own experience, the binary performs the same. It's the (powershell/windows terminal)conhost process that takes a lot of memory, and a lot of time to start up.

Comment: Right, but do not lump "(powershell/windows terminal)conhost" all into one thing – that makes no sense. Windows Terminal is not Conhost (though it does use a conhost-like "openconsole.exe" shim internally), and it's not even in the same category as PowerShell (which is not any kind of terminal or console at all, it's just a CLI shell). I'm not surprised that WT uses more resources than Conhost (both for the terminal app as a whole and for each additional text buffer), but that's completely independent from e.g. PowerShell being slower to initialize.

Comment: @user1686 I really, truly have no idea what you're saying. Whatever goes on "behind the scenes", internally in Windows, my question remains and has not been answered whatsoever. :/ And extreme CPU usage and lots of RAM usage cannot be attributed to GPU rendering...

Comment: @user1686 I tried your suggestion to turn on the Atlas engine thing, but it's the same thing: launching many terminals at once makes my system crawl on its knees, whereas cmd.exes can be launched without even noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I think you've got some confusion between what a terminal and a shell is. The Windows Terminal is a terminal emulator, which can run any shell, like CMD or PowerShell. "Conhost" (the vintage console window) was similarly a "terminal". @user1686 said as much above.

The Windows Terminal sets PowerShell as the default shell, but you can always change that to `cmd.exe` in the settings.

Can you file a minimal repro over on https://github.com/microsoft/terminal? The Terminal should be a *little* more resource intensive than conhost, sure. But I wouldn't expect the scenario you're describing to be as bad as you mention with the Windows Terminal set as the default terminal. It kinda sounds like whatever script is running is *intentionally* opening a pile of console windows, rather than reusing the one it was launched from. Or even more subtly - it's not passing the right flags to `CreateProcess` to create the console window hidden (which would keep Terminal out of the equation).